# ¿Como puedo hacer un STRING al iterar los valores de un ARRAY?

Tags: javascript, html

De una pantalla obtengo el `ID` y el `VALOR` de un grupo de `INPUT TEXT` con el siguiente código:

```
   var docs = document.getElementsByName('ftp_desc');

    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){

        console.log('id: ' + docs[i].id + ',' + 'value: ' + docs[i].value);
    }

 <input id="1" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
 <input id="2" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
 <input id="3" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
```

Como puedo hacer un STRING del arreglo de los ID y uno de los VALUE?

Ejemplo:

```
var ids = "1,2,3";
var values = "Desc1,Desc2,Desc3"
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo! como quieres que sea el string? con qué formato?, no entiendo bien.

Comment: Cuando itero  for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++)  
docs[i].id SON LOS ID 
docs[i].value SON LOS VALUE

Quiero crear un STRING con el conjunto de datos del arreglo de los ID y otro con el conjunto de datos del arreglo de los VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede hacer uso de los métodos [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) y [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values) para obtener los valores y claves de un `array` *(obj)* que crea y llena dentro del `for` , además del método [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) para darle el formato con un separador *(,)*

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('action');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
 var docs = document.getElementsByName('ftp_desc');
 var obj = {};//creamos el array
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
        obj[docs[i].id] = docs[i].value; // almacenamos los valores y clave id
    }
    console.log(Object.keys(obj).join(","));
    console.log(Object.values(obj).join(","));
});
```

```html
<input id="1" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
<input id="2" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
<input id="3" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
<button id="action">Aceptar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo añadiendo los ids y los valores que vayas encontrando en sus respectivas variables, para al finalizar tenerlas todas.

```
var docs = document.getElementsByName('ftp_desc');
var ids = '';
var values = '';

for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
    //Si es el último elemento no añado la coma, sino si la añado
    separator = (i == docs.length - 1) ? "" : ", ";
    //Agrego el nuevo id a la variable ids
    ids += docs[i].id+separator;
    //Agrego el nuevo valor a la variable values
    values += docs[i].value+separator;
    console.log('id: ' + docs[i].id + ',' + 'value: ' + docs[i].value);
}

//Aquí podras ver sus valores
console.log(ids);
console.log(values);
```